# Conditional ORDER BY on column with zeroes

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query I cannot wrap my head around. Let's say I have this table, `items` with 6 records

```
item_id     passage_id
==========  ==========
6           0
5           3
4           0
3           0
2           3
1           3
```

To get the records by descending `item_id`, I run the statement `SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY item_id DESC`, and the result is simply the same as the source table above.

But now it gets tricky. I now want to sort by descending `item_id`, but if there are other items with the same passage_id, I want them grouped by that passage_id.

```
item_id     passage_id
==========  ==========
6           0
5           3
2           3
1           3
4           0
3           0
```

How can I do this in a single SQL statement? The order is crucial because I need preserve it even when a limit is used:

`SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY ??? LIMIT 0, 3`

```
item_id     passage_id
==========  ==========
6           0
5           3
2           3
```

`SELECT * FROM items ORDER BY ??? LIMIT 2, 3`

```
item_id     passage_id
==========  ==========
1           3
4           0
3           0
```

EDIT: Here's the answer, taken from Gordon Linoff's answer below

```
SELECT i.item_id, i.passage_id 
FROM items i LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT i.passage_id, MAX(i.item_id) AS imax_id
    FROM items i 
    GROUP BY i.passage_id
) imax 
ON i.passage_id = imax.passage_id 
ORDER BY CASE WHEN i.passage_id=0 THEN i.item_id  ELSE imax.imax_id END DESC, i.item_id DESC;
```

Comment: `Order By item_id Desc, passage_id Desc`...?

Comment: That's not even close. He needs them grouped by `passage_id`. I don't think I've ever seen anyone do something like this before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to do something like keep the `passage_id`s together and sort these groups by the item ids.  The following should actually do this:

```
select i.item_id, i.passage_id
from items i join
     (select i.passage_id, max(i.item_id) as maxiid
      from items i
      group by i.passage_id
     ) imax
     on i.passage_id = i.passage_id
order by imax.maxiid,
         i.item_id desc;
```

But, it will not produce your ordering, because of `passage_id = 0`.  For these, you seem to want them based only on the `item_id` itself.  So, I think this encapsulates your logic:

```
select i.item_id, i.passage_id
from items i join
     (select i.passage_id, max(i.item_id) as maxiid
      from items i
      group by i.passage_id
     ) imax
     on i.passage_id = i.passage_id
order by (case when i.passage_id = 0 then i.item_id else imax.maxiid end) desc,
         i.item_id desc;
```

Comment: This worked, excellent! I knew I needed the CASE statement, but the join didn't occur to me.